# Having a hard time with delete-ing every nth element in Lisp?

Tags: list, lisp

Trying to learn lisp, want to delete every nth. I only managed to delete the first (nth) element

```
(defun delete-nth (n list)
(if (zerop n)
(cdr list)
(let ((cons (nthcdr (1- n) list)))
  (if cons
    (setf (cdr cons) (cddr cons))
    cons))))
```

I'd like to delete the next nth and so on

Also I tried this:

```
(defun remove-nth (list n)
(remove-if (constantly t) list :start n :end (+ 1 n)))
```

No idea how to start again

What I was thinking was concatenating, but I have no idea of how to keep track of my position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative way to do the same thing:

```
(defun remove-all-nth (list period)
   (remove-if
    (let ((iterator 0))
      (lambda (x)
        (declare (ignore x))
        (= 0 (mod (incf iterator) period)))) list))
(remove-all-nth '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0) 3)
; (1 2 4 5 7 8 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Counting from 1 (changing to 0 is trivial):

```
(defun remove-every-nth (n list)
  (loop for element in list
        for index from 1
        unless (zerop (rem index n))
          collect element))
```

Also: Please indent your code correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a more academic recursive solution here:

```
(defun delete-nth (n list)
  (labels ((rec (i list)
             (cond ((null list) nil)
                   ((= i 1) (rec n (cdr list)))
                   (t (cons (car list) (rec (1- i) (cdr list)))))))
    (rec n list)))
```

But in real life I'd use the loop option above.